# How can a custom font be used on a machine that doesn't have it installed?

Tags: vb.net, fonts

My WinForm application is using the Open Sans font which doesn't come installed by default on Windows computers so my question is how can I include it. I tried placing it in the resources of the project but with no avail. This thread was marked as a duplicate so I want to point out that I do not want to install the font on other computers I just don't want the default one to appear in my application (if it's actually possible) instead of the Open Sans font.